# Is there any way to reverse code after build project by typescript tsc command

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, source-maps

the project still have sourcemap file, using the typescript of version 4.7
Is there any way to reverse the code ?

using the [reverse-sourcemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverse-sourcemap) not working, return the message of "Not all sources were included in the sourcemap", probably is reverse-sourcemap version is too old and can not reverse the code

Comment: Do you mean to recover the source typescript code from JavaScript output?

Answer (score 0):

Your compiled JS seems to not include sources in it

There are two sourcemap variants:

- the "map" variant that maps *positions* in the code to the source *files*. sourceMappingURL comment is shorter then the code.
- the "source" variant that incudes source files. sourceMappingURL comment is 3 times longer then the code.